# Very strange segfault calling WinUsb_GetOverlappedResult

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, segmentation-fault, stdcall

I have this code:

```
void GetResult(WINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE InterfaceHandle, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
{
    DWORD numBytes = 0;
    WinUsb_GetOverlappedResult(
                InterfaceHandle,
                lpOverlapped,
                &numBytes,
                TRUE
                );
    return;

    uint8_t stack[64];
}
```

`WinUsb_GetOverlappedResult` is a `__stdcall` function declared as follows:

```
  WINBOOL WINAPI WinUsb_GetOverlappedResult (WINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE InterfaceHandle, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesTransferred, WINBOOL bWait);
```

Compiling in debug mode with GCC 5.3.0 (MinGW) it all works fine. (I can't compile with VC++ because I'm using GCC extensions.)

*However* if I change it to `stack[80]` then it segfaults!!

Here is the disassembly in each case. 64 (doesn't crash):

```
Dump of assembler code for function GetResult(void*, _OVERLAPPED*):
88    {
   0x00408523 <+0>:    push   %ebp
   0x00408524 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x00408526 <+3>:    sub    $0x68,%esp

89        DWORD numBytes = 0;
   0x00408529 <+6>:    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)

90        WinUsb_GetOverlappedResult(
91                    InterfaceHandle,
92                    lpOverlapped,
93                    &numBytes,
94                    TRUE
95                    );
=> 0x00408530 <+13>:    movl   $0x1,0xc(%esp)
   0x00408538 <+21>:    lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x0040853b <+24>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0x0040853f <+28>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x00408542 <+31>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x00408546 <+35>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x00408549 <+38>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x0040854c <+41>:    call   0x409d58 <WinUsb_GetOverlappedResult@16>
   0x00408551 <+46>:    sub    $0x10,%esp

96        return;
   0x00408554 <+49>:    nop

97        
98        uint8_t stack[64];
99    }
   0x00408555 <+50>:    leave  
   0x00408556 <+51>:    ret
```

And 80 (does crash):

```
Dump of assembler code for function GetResult(void*, _OVERLAPPED*):
88    {
   0x00408523 <+0>:    push   %ebp
   0x00408524 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x00408526 <+3>:    sub    $0x78,%esp

89        DWORD numBytes = 0;
   0x00408529 <+6>:    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)

90        WinUsb_GetOverlappedResult(
91                    InterfaceHandle,
92                    lpOverlapped,
93                    &numBytes,
94                    TRUE
95                    );
=> 0x00408530 <+13>:    movl   $0x1,0xc(%esp)
   0x00408538 <+21>:    lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x0040853b <+24>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0x0040853f <+28>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x00408542 <+31>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x00408546 <+35>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x00408549 <+38>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x0040854c <+41>:    call   0x409d58 <WinUsb_GetOverlappedResult@16>
   0x00408551 <+46>:    sub    $0x10,%esp

96        return;
   0x00408554 <+49>:    nop

97        
98        uint8_t stack[80];
99    }
   0x00408555 <+50>:    leave  
   0x00408556 <+51>:    ret
```

The effect of the `__stdcall` is to add the line `sub $0x10,%esp` which I guess is to cancel out `ret $0x10` in the function.

In any case these seem very similar and I have no idea why it is crashing. I'm not even 100% sure *where* it is crashing (GDB is rather unhelpful) but it is somewhere around WinUsb function call.

It's quite hard to debug because if I run the debugger with any breakpoints set, it doesn't crash. I suspect it may be timing related -
 I can also prevent the crash with a few extra `Sleep(100)`s. Once it seemed to crash in `PerfIncrementULongLongCounterValue()` but who knows...

Does anyone have any clue why this might be happening?

**Edit**

`WinUsb_GetOverlappedResult()` just calls straight through to `GetOverlappedResult()` according to its assembly, so I replace the call with that. Now you need `stack[96]` to cause the crash, but when it does it at least tells me where the real crash is (I think)!

Here is the disassembly of `GetOverlappedResult()`. It crashes where indicated because `ebp` is 0.

```
0x76feaba0                   8b ff                 mov    %edi,%edi
0x76feaba2  <+0x0002>        55                    push   %ebp
0x76feaba3  <+0x0003>        8b ec                 mov    %esp,%ebp
0x76feaba5  <+0x0005>        83 ec 0c              sub    $0xc,%esp
0x76feaba8  <+0x0008>        a1 94 4b 09 77        mov    0x77094b94,%eax
0x76feabad  <+0x000d>        33 c5                 xor    %ebp,%eax
0x76feabaf  <+0x000f>        89 45 fc              mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
0x76feabb2  <+0x0012>        83 7d 14 00           cmpl   $0x0,0x14(%ebp)
0x76feabb6  <+0x0016>        53                    push   %ebx
0x76feabb7  <+0x0017>        56                    push   %esi
0x76feabb8  <+0x0018>        57                    push   %edi
0x76feabb9  <+0x0019>        0f 84 b3 00 00 00     je     0x76feac72 <KERNELBASE!GetOverlappedResult+210>
0x76feabbf  <+0x001f>        83 cf ff              or     $0xffffffff,%edi
0x76feabc2  <+0x0022>        8b 5d 08              mov    0x8(%ebp),%ebx
0x76feabc5  <+0x0025>        83 cb 01              or     $0x1,%ebx
0x76feabc8  <+0x0028>        85 ff                 test   %edi,%edi
0x76feabca  <+0x002a>        0f 84 a9 00 00 00     je     0x76feac79 <KERNELBASE!GetOverlappedResult+217>
0x76feabd0  <+0x0030>        b8 01 00 00 00        mov    $0x1,%eax
0x76feabd5  <+0x0035>        c7 45 f4 01 00 00 00  movl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
0x76feabdc  <+0x003c>        89 45 f8              mov    %eax,-0x8(%ebp)
0x76feabdf  <+0x003f>        84 d8                 test   %bl,%al
0x76feabe1  <+0x0041>        0f 84 5e f3 03 00     je     0x77029f45 <KERNELBASE!GetCurrentProcess+43221>
0x76feabe7  <+0x0047>        6a 00                 push   $0x0
0x76feabe9  <+0x0049>        68 dc 10 f2 76        push   $0x76f210dc
0x76feabee  <+0x004e>        50                    push   %eax
0x76feabef  <+0x004f>        68 ab ab ab ab        push   $0xabababab
0x76feabf4  <+0x0054>        ff 15 68 80 09 77     call   *0x77098068
0x76feabfa  <+0x005a>        8b f0                 mov    %eax,%esi
0x76feabfc  <+0x005c>        85 f6                 test   %esi,%esi
0x76feabfe  <+0x005e>        74 0e                 je     0x76feac0e <KERNELBASE!GetOverlappedResult+110>
0x76feac00  <+0x0060>        8d 45 f4              lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x76feac03  <+0x0063>        8b ce                 mov    %esi,%ecx
0x76feac05  <+0x0065>        50                    push   %eax
0x76feac06  <+0x0066>        ff 15 5c 8a 09 77     call   *0x77098a5c
0x76feac0c  <+0x006c>        ff d6                 call   *%esi
0x76feac0e  <+0x006e>        33 c0                 xor    %eax,%eax
0x76feac10  <+0x0070>        83 e3 fe              and    $0xfffffffe,%ebx
0x76feac13  <+0x0073>        89 45 f8              mov    %eax,-0x8(%ebp)
0x76feac16  <+0x0076>        39 45 f4              cmp    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
0x76feac19  <+0x0079>        0f 85 26 f3 03 00     jne    0x77029f45 <KERNELBASE!GetCurrentProcess+43221>
0x76feac1f  <+0x007f>        8b 75 0c              mov    0xc(%ebp),%esi
0x76feac22  <+0x0082>        81 3e 03 01 00 00     cmpl   $0x103,(%esi)
0x76feac28  <+0x0088>        74 26                 je     0x76feac50 <KERNELBASE!GetOverlappedResult+176>

Crash:
0x76feac2a  <+0x008a>        8b 45 10              mov    0x10(%ebp),%eax

0x76feac2d  <+0x008d>        8b 4e 04              mov    0x4(%esi),%ecx
0x76feac30  <+0x0090>        89 08                 mov    %ecx,(%eax)
0x76feac32  <+0x0092>        8b 0e                 mov    (%esi),%ecx
0x76feac34  <+0x0094>        85 c9                 test   %ecx,%ecx
0x76feac36  <+0x0096>        78 31                 js     0x76feac69 <KERNELBASE!GetOverlappedResult+201>
0x76feac38  <+0x0098>        b8 01 00 00 00        mov    $0x1,%eax
0x76feac3d  <+0x009d>        8b 4d fc              mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ecx
0x76feac40  <+0x00a0>        5f                    pop    %edi
0x76feac41  <+0x00a1>        5e                    pop    %esi
0x76feac42  <+0x00a2>        33 cd                 xor    %ebp,%ecx
0x76feac44  <+0x00a4>        5b                    pop    %ebx
0x76feac45  <+0x00a5>        e8 0b f0 02 00        call   0x77019c55 <PerfIncrementULongLongCounterValue+197>
0x76feac4a  <+0x00aa>        8b e5                 mov    %ebp,%esp
0x76feac4c  <+0x00ac>        5d                    pop    %ebp
0x76feac4d  <+0x00ad>        c2 10 00              ret    $0x10
0x76feac50  <+0x00b0>        8b 46 10              mov    0x10(%esi),%eax
0x76feac53  <+0x00b3>        85 c0                 test   %eax,%eax
0x76feac55  <+0x00b5>        74 46                 je     0x76feac9d <KERNELBASE!GetOverlappedResult+253>
0x76feac57  <+0x00b7>        6a 00                 push   $0x0
0x76feac59  <+0x00b9>        57                    push   %edi
0x76feac5a  <+0x00ba>        50                    push   %eax
0x76feac5b  <+0x00bb>        e8 50 01 00 00        call   0x76feadb0 <WaitForSingleObjectEx>
0x76feac60  <+0x00c0>        85 c0                 test   %eax,%eax
0x76feac62  <+0x00c2>        74 c6                 je     0x76feac2a <KERNELBASE!GetOverlappedResult+138>
0x76feac64  <+0x00c4>        e9 fb f2 03 00        jmp    0x77029f64 <KERNELBASE!GetCurrentProcess+43252>
0x76feac69  <+0x00c9>        e8 d2 f1 ff ff        call   0x76fe9e40 <OpenThreadToken+64>
0x76feac6e  <+0x00ce>        33 c0                 xor    %eax,%eax
0x76feac70  <+0x00d0>        eb cb                 jmp    0x76feac3d <KERNELBASE!GetOverlappedResult+157>
0x76feac72  <+0x00d2>        33 ff                 xor    %edi,%edi
0x76feac74  <+0x00d4>        e9 49 ff ff ff        jmp    0x76feabc2 <KERNELBASE!GetOverlappedResult+34>
0x76feac79  <+0x00d9>        8b 75 0c              mov    0xc(%ebp),%esi
0x76feac7c  <+0x00dc>        81 3e 03 01 00 00     cmpl   $0x103,(%esi)
0x76feac82  <+0x00e2>        74 0a                 je     0x76feac8e <KERNELBASE!GetOverlappedResult+238>
0x76feac84  <+0x00e4>        33 c9                 xor    %ecx,%ecx
0x76feac86  <+0x00e6>        8d 45 f8              lea    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x76feac89  <+0x00e9>        f0 09 08              lock or %ecx,(%eax)
0x76feac8c  <+0x00ec>        eb 9c                 jmp    0x76feac2a <KERNELBASE!GetOverlappedResult+138>
0x76feac8e  <+0x00ee>        68 e4 03 00 00        push   $0x3e4
0x76feac93  <+0x00f3>        ff 15 c4 80 09 77     call   *0x770980c4
0x76feac99  <+0x00f9>        33 c0                 xor    %eax,%eax
0x76feac9b  <+0x00fb>        eb a0                 jmp    0x76feac3d <KERNELBASE!GetOverlappedResult+157>
0x76feac9d  <+0x00fd>        8b c3                 mov    %ebx,%eax
0x76feac9f  <+0x00ff>        eb b6                 jmp    0x76feac57 <KERNELBASE!GetOverlappedResult+183>
0x76feaca1  <+0x0101>        cc                    int3
0x76feaca2  <+0x0102>        cc                    int3
0x76feaca3  <+0x0103>        cc                    int3
0x76feaca4  <+0x0104>        cc                    int3
0x76feaca5  <+0x0105>        cc                    int3
0x76feaca6  <+0x0106>        cc                    int3
0x76feaca7  <+0x0107>        cc                    int3
0x76feaca8  <+0x0108>        cc                    int3
0x76feaca9  <+0x0109>        cc                    int3
0x76feacaa  <+0x010a>        cc                    int3
0x76feacab  <+0x010b>        cc                    int3
0x76feacac  <+0x010c>        cc                    int3
0x76feacad  <+0x010d>        cc                    int3
0x76feacae  <+0x010e>        cc                    int3
0x76feacaf  <+0x010f>        cc                    int3
```

Comment: where concrete exception ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand.

Comment: exception is where ? what here not understand ? and for what assemblu listing for `GetOverlappedResult` ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where the segfault is, but I believe it is where it says `Crash:` in the assembly listing of `GetOverlappedResult`, which is why I posted it.

Comment: The problem is most likely to be located in the code that initiates the I/O operation.  One of the most common errors is to free the I/O buffer (either implicitly or explicitly) before the I/O has actually completed.  In this case, I'd guess the I/O buffer was a local variable that has gone out of scope, and the I/O operation is overwriting the stack during the call to `GetOverlappedResult`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: right you are. I'll delete that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I *think* I figured this out. Maybe. The thing I changed is that I don't move my `OVERLAPPED` structure any more. I can only assume that WinUsb retains a pointer to the `OVERLAPPED` you pass when you start the write. If it moves then presumably things break.

This isn't mentioned anywhere I can find int the documentation for `OVERLAPPED` but changing my code so that the `OVERLAPPED` is dynamically allocated once and never moved seems to stop the crashes.

Unfortunately I never found a good way to debug it. The best way would be a reversible debugger but they don't seem to exist for Windows.

Comment: Yes, that would explain it.  Windows keeps a copy of the pointer to the `OVERLAPPED` structure, and writes to the `Internal` and `InternalHigh` members (from the kernel) when the I/O completes.  It probably reads from it too.  The requirement to not deallocate or modify the `OVERLAPPED` structure is described in [Synchronous and Asynchronous I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683(v=vs.85).aspx).  It is unfortunate that the documentation for `OVERLAPPED` doesn't mention this directly.  It's one of those things Microsoft thought would be obvious, I guess.

Comment: Aha good find! Nice to know that it wasn't a fluke. I'm going to poke MS to update their documentation.

Comment: Ok I submitted feedback to a few MSDN pages, e.g. for `OVERLAPPED`, `GetOverlappedResult`, `WinUsb_WritePipe`. If you're reading this in 2018 and they still don't mention it then at least you know that the Feedback option on MSDN pages has no effect.

Comment: I don't *think* that feedback goes directly into the bitbucket, but I'm not sure who it goes to or how seriously they take it.  Technical documentation always seems to be a problem, I suspect it is hard to find people who are both good at writing and at technology.  It used to be possible for us to leave comments on MSDN pages for future readers, but that functionality seems to have disappeared. :-(