# Debugging timing-dependent Windows segfaults

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

I have [some C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521760/very-strange-segfault-calling-winusb-getoverlappedresult) that crashes in a very confusing way in WinUsb. The crash is timing-dependent (i.e. if I slowly step through execution it doesn't happen), non-local (e.g. if I move one function call inside another function, it makes a third function crash) and when it crashes it more or less always corrupts the stack.

I'm also using MinGW which only outputs DWARF debugging info - not PDBs. So some tools (e.g. x64dbg) can't show debugging info.

Is there any possible way to debug this? On Linux I would use a reversible debugger like `rr` but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for Windows. Does anyone know of any useful tools or techniques for this?

Comment: In this particular case, the most likely cause is that the user-mode stack is being corrupted from kernel mode.  So I don't think any user-mode debugging tool will be of much help.

Comment: You might be interested in Microsoft's pre-release [Time Travel Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview).  Wouldn't have helped in this case because your problem involved interaction with the kernel, but FYI.